# Data on user-user trust ratings and user-item ratings

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, research, trust

I am doing a research project on Recommender System, where I need data of user-item ratings and user-user trust ratings. Publicly available similar datasets are

- [Film trust dataset](https://www.librec.net/datasets.html)
- [Epinion dataset](http://www.trustlet.org/downloaded_epinions.html)

Both have user-item ratings but don't have user-user trust ratings; instead they have user-user trust statement. Also they only contain positive trust statement and don't have negative trust statement.

The difference between statement and ratings is, statement can only have value of 1(trusted) or -1(not trusted), but rating will have values in range 0-5 or 0-1.

So is there any prior work on this type dataset and where can I find these type dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Such type doesn't exist till now. The best one can do is, calculate the trust values using some trust metric. There are many trust metrics available out of which many use user-item rating matrix as input. So one can use user-item rating data to calculate the user-user trust values.

To know about trust metrics, here is one [survey paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5de2/058bf3bc94b9f463ab040c07ffaf3a79e9e8.pdf) on trust metrics.

Comment: Sorry, but you can never conclude that *Such type doesn't exist till now*. You were unable to find any, that's different.

Comment: I actively work on this area. After 1 yr of research, I am telling this.

Comment: @JanDoggen No comments??